# What is the method data in the JVM specification and what is it for?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm reading [the jvm specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4), It states that the 'Method Area' stores per-class structures such as the run-time constant pool, field and method data, and the code for methods and constructors.

I know what the run-time constant pool is. I guess the field and method data is the code for methods and constructors that code programmers write or the bytecode jdk compiled, but what exactly is the method data?

Comment: Read the following article from Artima on the [Method Area](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm5.html)

Comment: Basically the method area is "everything that isn't somewhere else".  It's only documented because there may be a means to control its size and because if it fills up you can get an out-of-storage condition.  The largest portion of the data (ignoring the JITC) is probably the per-class internal representations of class structures, method tables, etc.  And then there's the storage required by the JITC, which may be bundled in with the "method area" or may be somewhere else.

Comment: Edwin Dalorzo - Sorry, I didn't see your link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the five runtime logical memory areas of the JVM, like the Heap, the stack, the native stack, etc...  See [Inside the JVM](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm5.html).

This is what it does:

When the Java virtual machine loads a type, it uses a class loader to locate the appropriate class file. The class loader reads in the class file--a linear stream of binary data--and passes it to the virtual machine. The virtual machine extracts information about the type from the binary data and stores the information in the method area. Memory for class (static) variables declared in the class is also taken from the method area.

The Type Information:

For each type it loads, a Java virtual machine must store the following kinds of information in the method area:

- The fully qualified name of the type
- The fully qualified name of the type's direct superclass (unless the type is an interface or class java.lang.Object, neither of which have a superclass)
- Whether or not the type is a class or an interface
- The type's modifiers ( some subset of` public, abstract, final)
- An ordered list of the fully qualified names of any direct superinterfaces

Here is a picture to illustrate:
[image]